# merge two Map Values in Java and if key is same append the Values not overwrite in Java 7 or Java 8

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, mergemap

I want to merge 2 `Map`s, but when the key is the same, the values should be appended instead of overwritten.

Let's say

```java
Map<String, Set<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
set1.add("AB");
set1.add("BC");
map1.put("ABCD",set1);

Map<String, Set<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
Set<String> set2 =new HashSet<>();
set2.add("CD");
set2.add("EF");
map2.put("ABCD",set2);

map1.putAll(map2);
```

So here the key is same.I know putAll will overwrite the values if key is same

But I am looking for an output like

```
{ABCD=[AB,BC,CD,ED]}
```

If someone can help me to resolve, will be so thankful.

Comment: As result you want to modify one of maps, or create entirely new map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make use of the merging function provided to [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) that specifies what to do with values of duplicate keys with Streams. <sup>[Demo](https://ideone.com/sIN7ow)</sup>

```
final Map<String, Set<String>> map3 = Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                (a, b) -> Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```

You can apply a similar approach using [`Map#merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-). <sup>[Demo](https://ideone.com/kohcms)</sup>

```
final Map<String, Set<String>> map3 = new HashMap<>(map1);
map2.forEach((key, val) -> map3.merge(key, val,
        (a, b) -> Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can concat two maps using `Stream.concat` then collect using `groupingBy` map key and value as Set.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> res = 
       Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream())
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e-> e.getKey(),
                                Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), Collectors.toSet())));
```

*Note:* Solution use Java 9+ `flatMapping`

Or

You can use `merge` function of map. Here merge `map2` data into `map1`

```
map2.forEach((key, val) -> map1.merge(key, val, (a, b) -> {a.addAll(b); return a;}));
```

Output: `{ABCD=[AB, BC, CD, EF]}`

Comment: `flatMapping` is java-9, though.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I missed that part accually

Comment: no worries, this the nicest anyway, imho. 1+

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Stream API** to merge the values of the same keys, Check if the `map2` has the same keys from `map1` and loop over them and merge the values together using `addAll()`

```
map1.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> map2.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
                .forEach(entry -> entry.getValue().addAll(map2.get(entry.getKey())));
```

---

, `main` function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    set1.add("AB");
    set1.add("BC");
    map1.put("ABCD", set1);

    Map<String, Set<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();
    set2.add("CD");
    set2.add("EF");
    map2.put("ABCD", set2);

    map1.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> map2.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
        .forEach(entry -> entry.getValue().addAll(map2.get(entry.getKey())));

    System.out.println(map1);
}
```

, `output`

```
{ABCD=[AB, BC, CD, EF]}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not getting the correct output 


`Map 1 -> {fghjk=[AB, BC], ABCD=[AB, BC]}
Map 2 -> {CDDFF=[CD, AB], ABCD=[CD, AB]}
ResultMap  After Merge -> {fghjk=[AB, BC, CD], ABCD=[AB, BC, CD]}`

Need output like :-

`ResultMap  After Merge -> {fghjk=[AB, BC], ABCD=[AB, BC, CD], CDDFF=[CD, AB]}`